# React-Native after enabling proguard the app crashes

Tags: react-native

Build Config:

```
enableProguardInReleaseBuilds=true
```

> cd android && ./gradlew installRelease

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to configure proguard..
Check the RN official docs [here.](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#enabling-proguard-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-apk-optional)

> Proguard is a tool that can slightly reduce the size of the APK. It
>   does this by stripping parts of the React Native Java bytecode (and
>   its dependencies) that your app is not using.
>
> ***IMPORTANT***: Make sure to thoroughly test your app if you've enabled
>   Proguard. Proguard often requires configuration specific to each
>   native library you're using. See app/proguard-rules.pro.

Comment: How Can I configuration these? I'm Facing the same issue!